# How are nicknames determined?

Tags: poker-night-2

Throughout your careers in either Poker Night at The Inventory or Poker Night 2, your 'nickname' (something like Ziggy Flophouser or whatever) will consistently change depending on your stats throughout. I've been wondering, however, what the different stats are that determine all the nicknames.

**What are all the available nicknames in the two Poker Night games, and what are the criteria for them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player Names in Poker Night were awarded based on a combination of your wins versus losses, measured against how long you had been playing. Here are some which I've encountered. They still manage to crack me up.

Paws Hogg, Poker Pro
Ace Ginger, Stunt Pilot
Rake Frechman, Money Aficionado
Max Ides: The Middling Killer

Ziggy Flophouser
Remy Rebuy, The Optimist
Dame Olive Cardpalm
Artie Flopshark, Deceased

Chet Chester, Cheddar Checker
Chin "The Chilla Chin" Chiller
Suzy Sideking
Hamilton "Short" Stacks

Poorpockets McNewhols
“Leaky" Milkstraw
Bobo Woodcoin
Mickey Mensch The Pocket Padder

Source: [Telltale Community](https://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/44457/all-poker-night-poker-names)

Comment: If you're going to [copy from somewhere](https://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/44457/all-poker-night-poker-names), you are required to attribute your source.  Not doing so makes your content subject to deletion.